# Prove that (V,T) is a cyclic $F[x]$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, linear-transformations

I'm working on some problems on modules, and stumbled onto a problem that is closely related to linear algebra and came to a stall.

The problem is:

Suppose $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.

Prove that $(V,T)$ is a cyclic $F[x]$-module iff there exists a vector $v_0 \in V$ such that the vectors $v_oT, v_0T^2...v_oT^{n-1}$ are linearly independent.

Could anyone shed some light on which direction to take this question?

Comment: Isn't that the *definition* of cyclic module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V$ is given the structure of an $F[x]$-module by taking the scalars in $F$ to act on vectors in $V$ by scalar multiplication, and by taking $x$ to act as the linear transformation $T$ on vectors in $V$.

For the "if" part, you know that $V$ is generated by $\{ v_0, \dots, T^{n-1}v_0 \}$ as a module over $F$, since this is a basis for $V$ over $F$. Can I suggest you show that $V$ is generated by the single element $v_0$ as a module over $F[x]$?

I'll leave you to work out the "only if" part.

Comment: Can we deduce this just from the definition? Since for V to be cyclic, for some $a \in V$, $V = F[x]*a = \{p(x)a | p(x) \in F[x] \}$, and we just take $p(x) = T^0, T, T^2... T^{n-1}$?

Comment: And the converse just comes from the definition of span?

Comment: Well, a general element of $V$ looks like a linear combination, $v = a_0v_0 + a_1 Tv_0 + a_2 T^2 v_0 + \dots + a_{n-1} T^{n-1} v_0$. So this element can be written as $p(x)v_0$, where $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ a_2x^2 + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$.

Comment: For the converse, if $V$ is cyclic, then $V$ is generated by some $v_0$ as a module over $F[x]$. Therefore, $V$ is generated by $\{ v_0, Tv_0, T^2 v_0, T^3 v_0, \dots \}$ as a vector space over $F$. Then use the fact that $V$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $F$.